# Moving text - pretty cool but can I add start/stop on Events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

Hi this is cool script to for moving text: 
http://jsfiddle.net/stephaniie/48makvau

Im trying to make it start/stop when something happens on my Page.

my Page: http://stephaniie.com/_testlab/beta1/

Any tips?

my page code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dark Souls for Travellers</title>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="assets/js/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js"></script>

    <script src="assets/js/1-11-1jquery.min.js"></script>                       <!-- JQuery 1.1.  -->
    <script src="assets/js/1-11-1jquery-ui.min.js"></script>                    <!-- JQuery 1.1.  -->
    <script src="assets/js/toolitup-minimap.min.js"></script>                   <!-- MINIMAP  -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/colorbox-assets/colorbox.css" />                                        <!-- COLORBOX -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/minimap.alt.css" />                                             <!-- MINIMAP  -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/assets/css/emojione.min.css"/>      <!--SHOUTBOX  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style-test.css" />                                                  <!--SHOUTBOX  --> 

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Griffy" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
    display: block
    .nospace {
        font-size: 0;
    }
    img[usemap] {
        border: none;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto%;
    }

    html, body, figure { 
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .back{
        background-color : #fffee0; //add background color
    }
    #img2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 80vw;
        left:30vw;
        display: none;
        width: 40vw;
     }
     #type {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30vw;
        left:30vw;
        display: block;
        width: 40vw;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 200;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
        #shout {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>    
</head>
<body>

<div id="toolbar-options" class="back">

<div id="type"></div>

  <img id="img2" src="solaire-big-ani-smaller.gif" alt=""/>

<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/01-alt.gif" usemap="#map01" id="img_id01"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/02.gif" usemap="#map02" id="img_id02"/> 
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/03.gif" usemap="#map03" id="img_id03"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/04.gif" usemap="#map04" id="img_id04"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/05.gif" usemap="#map05" id="img_id05"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/06.gif" usemap="#map06" id="img_id06"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/07.gif" usemap="#map07" id="img_id07"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/08.gif" usemap="#map08" id="img_id08"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/09.gif" usemap="#map09" id="img_id09"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/10.gif" usemap="#map10" id="img_id10"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/11.gif" usemap="#map11" id="img_id11"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/12.gif" usemap="#map12" id="img_id12"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/13.gif" usemap="#map13" id="img_id13"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/14.gif" usemap="#map14" id="img_id14"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/15.gif" usemap="#map15" id="img_id15"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/16.gif" usemap="#map16" id="img_id16"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/17.gif" usemap="#map17" id="img_id17"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/18.gif" usemap="#map18" id="img_id18"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/19.gif" usemap="#map19" id="img_id19"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/20.gif" usemap="#map20" id="img_id20"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/21.gif" usemap="#map21" id="img_id21"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/22.gif" usemap="#map22" id="img_id22"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/23.gif" usemap="#map23" id="img_id23"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/24.gif" usemap="#map24" id="img_id24"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/25.gif" usemap="#map25" id="img_id25"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/26.gif" usemap="#map26" id="img_id26"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/27.gif" usemap="#map27" id="img_id27"/>
<img src="assets/images/no-text/day/28-alt.gif" usemap="#map28" id="img_id28"/>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 400px; left: 0px;" class="shoutbox" id="shout">     
    <h1><!-- <img src='./assets/images/refresh.png'/> --> </h1>    
    <ul class="shoutbox-content"></ul>    
    <div class="shoutbox-form">
        <h2> <span>×</span></h2>
        <form action="publish.php" method="post">
            <label for="shoutbox-name">Name </label> <input type="text" id="shoutbox-name" name="name"/>
            <label class="shoutbox-comment-label" for="shoutbox-comment"> </label> 
            <textarea id="shoutbox-comment" name="comment" maxlength='240'></textarea>
            <input position="center" type="image" src="soap.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

   <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="66,628,276,830" shape="rect">


<map name="map01" id="img_id01">
<area class="link" coords="3503,673,359" shape="circle" href="index-afternoon.html"  target="_parent" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id01').src= 'assets/images/logo-sun/day-alt.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id01').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/01-alt.gif';"  />
<area class="link" alt="kotaku" title="kotaku" href="http://kotaku.com/lordran-the-setting-of-dark-souls-almost-entirely-red-1682735168" coords="26,270,956,87" shape="rect" target="_blank" style="outline:none;"/>
<area class="link" alt="facebook" title="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/tettix/" coords="276,488,58,313" shape="rect" target="_blank" style="outline:none;"/>
<area class="link" alt="website" title="website" href="http://tettix.net/lordran/lordran.html" coords="388,599,50,520" shape="rect" target="_blank" style="outline:none;"/>
<area class="link" alt="website" title="website" href="http://servantofentropy.deviantart.com/art/Dark-souls-enemies-511984399" coords="66,628,276,830" shape="rect" target="_blank" style="outline:none;"/>
</map>

<map name="map02" id="img_id02">
<area class="youtube" coords="1238,147,1381,24" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BBqkap40QAo" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id02').src= 'assets/images/text/day/02.gif'; PlaySound('02');" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id02').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/02.gif'; StopSound('02');"  />
</map>

<map name="map05" id="img_id05">
<area class="youtube" coords="2224,143,2308,277" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ipsKKb-o334" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id05').src= 'assets/images/text/day/05.gif'; PlaySound('05giant');" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id05').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/05.gif'; StopSound('05giant');"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="2653,95,2872,257" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/my-yq5xf8YY" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id05').src= 'assets/images/text/day/05os.gif'; PlaySound('05os');" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id05').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/05.gif'; StopSound('05os'); PlaySound('05os-stop');"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="2757,345,2836,447" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lm_9tk0h9hM" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id05').src= 'assets/images/text/day/05gwyn.gif'; PlaySound('05gwyn');" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id05').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/05.gif'; StopSound('05gwyn');" />
</map>

<map name="map07" id="img_id07">
<area class="youtube" coords="1107,178,1171,253" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZzcA_G5ujGk" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/text/day/07.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/07.gif';"  />          

<area class="youtube" coords="1922,150,2006,265" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nNhrS2hEicc" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/text/day/07golem.gif'; PlaySound('07golem');"
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/07.gif'; StopSound('07golem');" />

<area class="youtube" coords="2391,91,2566,198" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mO5Bbr9D4J0" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/text/day/07guardian.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/07.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="3707,47,3862,150" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/asDH5OBHT9o" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/text/day/07sif.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id07').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/07.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map09" id="img_id09">
<area class="youtube" coords="1604,214,1676,301" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AEix6sRiAL4" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id09').src= 'assets/images/text/day/09.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id09').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/09.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="2391,158,2590,273" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cSkbH8fVvpk" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id09').src= 'assets/images/text/day/09butterfly.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id09').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/09.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map10" id="img_id10">
<area class="youtube" coords="1222,75,1302,150" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cdliu3JOSYQ" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id10').src= 'assets/images/text/day/10.gif'; PlaySound('siegmeyer');"
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id10').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/10.gif'; StopSound('siegmeyer');"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="3476,4,3647,107" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YkKWdrdxngo" style="outline:none;" 
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id10').src= 'assets/images/text/day/10taurus.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id10').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/10.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map11" id="img_id11">
<area class="youtube" coords="801,75,884,0" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4enuU8R8Iuk" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id11').src= 'assets/images/text/day/11.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id11').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/11.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="984,79,1135,186" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eQx-j0aklhE" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id11').src= 'assets/images/text/day/11bell.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id11').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/11.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map12" id="img_id12">
<area class="youtube" coords="1497,52,1588,128" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GPbUA6dCR8k" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src= 'assets/images/text/day/12.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/12.gif';"  />

<!-- <area class="youtube" coords="3878,24,3957,96" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/skV-q5KjrUA" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src= 'assets/images/text/day/12solaire-ani.gif'; PlaySound('solaire');"
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/12.gif'; StopSound('solaire'); PlaySound('solaire-stop');"  />  -->
<area class="youtube" id="sol" coords="3878,24,3957,96" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/skV-q5KjrUA" style="outline:none;" /> 
</map> 

<map name="map14" id="img_id14">
<area class="youtube" coords="2407,99,2467,171" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/aRgHcTNfKAw" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id14').src= 'assets/images/text/day/14.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id14').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/14.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="3266,28,3421,123" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hkq1myppcok" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id14').src= 'assets/images/text/day/14capra.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id14').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/14.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map15" id="img_id15">
<area class="youtube" coords="2157,28,2363,143" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/afee2HDyTnA" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id15').src= 'assets/images/text/day/15.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id15').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/15.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map17" id="img_id17">
<area class="youtube" coords="2220,55,2335,166" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/D6DDrwH0OvU" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id17').src= 'assets/images/text/day/17kalameet.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id17').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/17.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="3170,135,3353,238" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kVk4vtLEEV8" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id17').src= 'assets/images/text/day/17.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id17').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/17.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map19" id="img_id19">
<area class="youtube" coords="1672,103,1966,269" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eRbZVx6SuOE" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id19').src= 'assets/images/text/day/19.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id19').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/19.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map21" id="img_id21">
<area class="youtube" coords="2387,179,2518,358" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CtR-7_XqJew" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id21').src= 'assets/images/text/day/21.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id21').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/21.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map22" id="img_id22">
<area class="youtube" coords="984,32,1063,104" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ioSArdWOWMA" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id22').src= 'assets/images/text/day/22.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id22').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/22.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="1485,96,1604,208" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7eJeUG1m6eI" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id22').src= 'assets/images/text/day/22pinwheel.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id22').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/22.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="3349,144,3584,264" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hdS2hW5Iiq4" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id22').src= 'assets/images/text/day/22firesage.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id22').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/22.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map23" id="img_id23">
<area class="youtube" coords="1954,12,2125,115" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Lp_VHdSdhg0" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id23').src= 'assets/images/text/day/23.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id23').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/23.gif';"  />

<area class="youtube" coords="3377,56,3588,171" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T3_V9NhUwPM" style="outline:none;" 
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id23').src= 'assets/images/text/day/23centipede.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id23').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/23.gif';"  />

<map name="map24" id="img_id24">
<area class="youtube" coords="2125,76,2363,258" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LaIJpVwKgZw" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id24').src= 'assets/images/text/day/24.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id24').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/24.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map26" id="img_id26">
<area class="youtube" coords="745,52,805,107" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZBN-t9R3Szo" style="outline:none;"
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id26').src= 'assets/images/text/day/26-b.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id26').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/26.gif';"  />
</map>

<map name="map27" id="img_id27">
<area class="youtube" coords="2467,147,2598,275" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/exzFsi0-DFo" style="outline:none;" 
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id27').src= 'assets/images/text/day/27.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id27').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/27.gif';"  />
</map> 

<map name="map28" id="img_id28">
<area class="youtube" coords="1799,1639,2081,1866" shape="rect" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/E-QxQhZid_E" style="outline:none;" 
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id28').src= 'assets/images/text/day/28-alt.gif';" 
onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id28').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/28-alt.gif';"  />
</map> 
</div>


<!-- Image Appear/Hide -->
<script>
    var img1 = document.getElementById("sol"),
    img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

    img1.onmouseover = function() {
        img2.style.display = "block";
        if (document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src = 'assets/images/text/day/12solaire-ani.gif';  PlaySound('solaire');
    }

    img1.onmouseout = function() {
        img2.style.display = "none";
        if (document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src = 'assets/images/no-text/day/12.gif'; StopSound('solaire'); PlaySound('solaire-stop');
    }   
</script>

<!-- SHOUTBOX -->
<script>
function PlaySound(soundobj) {
    var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.play();
}
function StopSound(soundobj) {
    var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.pause();
    thissound.currentTime = 0;
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:1024, innerHeight:576});
});
function setHalfVolume() {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById("05os"); 
    var myAudio2 = document.getElementById("05os-stop");
    var myAudio3 = document.getElementById("07golem");
    var myAudio4 = document.getElementById("05gwyn");
    var myAudio5 = document.getElementById("05giant");
    var myAudio6 = document.getElementById("02");
    myAudio.volume = 0.1; 
    myAudio2.volume = 0.2; 
    myAudio3.volume = 0.1;
    myAudio4.volume = 0.2;
    myAudio5.volume = 0.2;
    myAudio6.volume = 0.2;
}
</script> 

<!-- audio files -->
<audio id='02' src='assets/wav/02.m4a' onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()"/>
<audio id='05gwyn' src='assets/wav/05gwyn.mp3'/>
<audio id='05os' src='assets/wav/05os.mp3' onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()"/>
<audio id='05os-stop' src='assets/wav/05os-stop.mp3' onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()"/>
<audio id='05gwyn' src='assets/wav/05gwyn.mp3' onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()"/>
<audio id='solaire' src='assets/wav/solaire-new.mp3'/>
<audio id='solaire-stop' src='assets/wav/solaire-stop.mp3'/>
<audio id='05giant' src='assets/wav/05giant.mp3' onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()"/>
<audio id='siegmeyer' src='assets/wav/siegmeyer.mp3'/>
<audio id='07golem' src='assets/wav/07golem.mp3' onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()"/>


<!-- Javascripts -->
<script src="assets/colorbox-assets/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>           
<script src="assets/js/minimap.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/emojione/1.3.0/lib/js/emojione.min.js"></script> 
<script src="./assets/js/script2.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var mousex = e.pageX -50; //Get X coordinates
                var mousey = e.pageY +25; //Get Y coordinates
                $('.tooltip')
                .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
        }); 
});
</script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.imagemapster.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script> -->



<script>
$.fn.typer = function(text, options){
    options = $.extend({}, {
        char: ' ',
        delay: 1000,
        duration: 600,
        endless: true
    }, options || text);

    text = $.isPlainObject(text) ? options.text : text;

    var elem = $(this),
        isTag = false,
        c = 0;

    (function typetext(i) {
        var e = ({string:1, number:1}[typeof text] ? text : text[i]) + options.char,
            char = e.substr(c++, 1);

        if( char === '<' ){ isTag = true; }
        if( char === '>' ){ isTag = false; }
        elem.html(e.substr(0, c));
        if(c <= e.length){
            if( isTag ){
                typetext(i);
            } else {
                setTimeout(typetext, options.duration/10, i);
            }
        } else {
            c = 0;
            i++;

            if (i === text.length && !options.endless) {
                return;
            } else if (i === text.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            setTimeout(typetext, options.delay, i);
        }
    })(0);
};
$('#type').typer(['a <b>cool</b> affect', 'made with <b>js<b>', 'format your <i>text</i> here', 'im watching <b>you</b>' ]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im using it here. http://stephaniie.com/_testlab/beta1/

Comment: the bootply.com doesn't work.

Comment: and as @MichaelCoker said booply.com ain't working

Comment: @MichaelCoker: WoW. that guy just removed it from that page. I added the same code on JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/stephaniie/48makvau/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stephaniie/48makvau/

Comment: @MichaelCoker Can you view the code now, ? =)

Comment: @StephanieHallberg Here is an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn3wgyk7/), sure you get the idea.

Comment: You should try detecting some another element on your page then you can start your script.

Comment: Ty I saved your fiddle =). How can i promote your answer, as answer? :)